# Extreme high autocorrelation in MCMCglmm but good prediction

Tags: logistic, bayesian, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am fitting a logistic regression model without random effects with options set to:

```
list(R = list(V=1, fix = 1))
nitt=100000
burnin=30000
```

The data set is very small, around 100 observations. I have categorical and numeric predictors.

The auto-correlation is pretty bad in the model for most predictors, and the posterior mean estimates are correspondingly crazy, and keep increasing as I increase the number of iterations. HOWEVER, the predictive power is great. In leave-one-out corss-validation (which is what I am interested in), the model performs perfectly most of the time (some times it makes one error).

What does this mean? I understand that the estimates must be wrong, but can I claim the model is in fact doing something right?

[image]

Comment: Can you display the acf plots or traceplots?

Comment: Try some other packages to compare your estimates like glmm or mcemGLM.

Comment: @Greenparker I have added an example. It makes no sense to compare estimates because they just keep changing as increase iterations.

Comment: Yes, I understand the estimates keep on changing using the MCMCglmm package, but maybe the other packages give you estimates that do not change. I saw this because implementing glmm effectively is still very much a research area, so its possible all packages don't work perfectly.